# Find sum every nth number of cells in a column Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to create a formula that will enable me to find the sum of every nth number of cells in a column.

For example, finding the sum of `A1:A10`, `A11:A20`, `A21:A30`...and for the sum to be placed in a different column (e.g. `D1`, `D2`, `D3`...).

However, I am not sure how many cells I want to sum up, so I stated an example earlier. 
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not sure how many cells I want to sum up"? How does a forumla decide how many it should sum up?

Comment: @user3120285 have you tried formulating the cell as per the answer below,any error??

Answer (score 3):

You can try this formula

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A:A,(ROW()-1)*10,0,10))
```

Comment: nice approach :D. I do some fixes based on my data like this `=SUM(OFFSET(A:A,(ROW(A1)-1)*$B$1,0,$B$1))` where `B1` contains the number of items for summation. :)

Comment: +1 although not sure why not `$A$1` rather than `A:A`?

Answer (score 2):

Using this approach will put the explicit formulas in column D, e.g. in D1 `=SUM(A1:A10)`, in D2 `=SUM(A11:A20)` etc...

Put this formula in D1

`="=SUM(A"&1+(ROWS(D$1:D1)-1)*10&":A"&ROWS(D$1:D1)*10&")"`

copy that down as far as required

Now copy the data and use right-click > Paste Special > Values

That gives you the correct formulas as text strings - to convert to real formulas do this

Select range > Find & Replace > Replace > use **=** in "find what" and also **=** in "Replace With" > Replace All > OK > ESC

Answer (score 0):

This is a quiet simple task,please follow below steps::

1.Select the column where you want to place the sum of the n columns for example say `D1`

2.Then in the formula bar write the formula for sum like `=SUM(A1:A10)`

3.And to repeat this formula just drag the copy the cell i.e `D1` and paste upto the column where you want the sum to be places say for example `D10`.

This will place the sum of cells A1 to A10 into the cell D1 .

Comment: ...but it wont put `=SUM(A11:A20)` into `D2` etc. Which is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A" & ROW(A1)*$B$1-($B$1-1) &":" & "A" & ROW(A1)*$B$1))
```

Where your data looks like this:

[image]

`B1` contains the number of cells you want to sum.
Transfer it where you want.
Hope this helps.

Comment: i don't know why i was downvoted :p Something wrong with my formula? :)